# Using browser.get causes asynchronous script timeout

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm using protractor for my automation testing and i encountered the following behavior:

when i try to use browser.get to load a certin page the page is loaded but i get the following error:

```
Error while running testForAngular: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds.
```

I use the browser.get in the following way:

```
beforeEach(function() {
     browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
     browser.get('https://.../Automation_VF');
     browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
},60000);

it(data.testProperties.Description, function () {

       browser.executeScript('return RemoteActions;')
       .then(function(remoteAction) {
                browser.executeAsyncScript(function(remoteAction) {
                var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
                    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(remoteAction.clearAllData, function (res, ev) {
                        callback(res);
                    }, { buffer: false, escape: false, timeout: 15000 });
                },remoteAction).then(function(res) {
                    console.log("executing async script");
                    console.log(res);
                });
        });
});
```

My conf file is:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['multiTestRun.js'],
  getPageTimeout: 60000,
  rootElement: '[ng-app]',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
      showColors: true,
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 10000000,
      isVerbose: true,
      includeStackTrace: true
  },
  ...
};
```

The page Automation_VF is non angular page.
If i try to use the browser.get command after browser.ignoreSynchronization is set true the page is not lodaed.

My question is why do i get the error mentioned above (the error happens even when all of the code inside the it block is commented out) and how can i make the browser.get command to work with the execute script commands inside the it block ?

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to use page objects and extract the Automation_VF page which would then handle the retrieval of the page itself. That way your objects know how to get themselves and your specs know how to disable/enable synchronization. [This](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md) may help get you moving.

Comment: Moving the get action to page object as you suggested doesn't help i still get the same error message any other suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried starting with a simple get page test? It looks like your doing a lot of different things and it may be **helpful to start from a known state**. For example cut out the before each and other properties functionality and just do a basic describe and it test that can just call out and get the page. Verify you can get there and **then** start adding things. Sometimes when I hit a wall I need to back track and get myself to a positive state.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue after converting the it block to the following form:

```
it(data.testProperties.Description, function () {
       browser.get('https://.../Automation_VF');
       browser.get('https://.../Automation_VF');

       browser.executeScript('return RemoteActions;')
       .then(function(remoteAction) {
                browser.executeAsyncScript(function(remoteAction) {
                var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
                    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(remoteAction.clearAllData, function (res, ev) {
                        callback(res);
                    }, { buffer: false, escape: false, timeout: 15000 });
                },remoteAction).then(function(res) {
                    console.log("executing async script");
                    console.log(res);
                });
        });
});
```

Seems that when there was only one get action the requested page was not loaded and doing two get actions fixed it.